# how to overwrite the existing object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to add existing matched values in object and add the remaining values in javascript 
for example, i need to merge_obj with my_obj having id '1' , matched values targetAmount only replace and remaining properties need to add

I tried

```
var filtervalue = my_obj.filter((e)=>e.id == "1").map((e)=>Object.assign({},e[0], merge_obj));
```

```
const merge_obj = {
  targetAmount: 50688.97,
  type: "REGULAR"
}

const my_obj = [
  {
    id: "1",
    logo: "img1.png",
    name: "fund",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "2000"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    logo: "img2.png",
    name: "transfer",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "3000"
  },
]


Expected Output:
var my_obj = [
{
    id: "1",
    logo: "img1.png",
    name: "fund",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: 50688.97,
    type: "REGULAR",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    logo: "img2.png",
    name: "transfer",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "3000",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just merge the first one by checking `id`:

```js
var my_obj = [{
    id: "1",
    logo: "img1.png",
    name: "fund",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "2000"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    logo: "img2.png",
    name: "transfer",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "3000"
  },
]

var merge_obj = {
  targetAmount: 50688.97,
  type: "REGULAR"
};

var new_obj = my_obj.map(e => {
  if (e.id == "1") {
    Object.keys(merge_obj).forEach(key => e[key] = merge_obj[key]);
  }
  return e;
});
console.log(new_obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved my using the array map method to iterate through the array of objects, checking if the id is equivalent to '1', followed by using ES6's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to 'merge' the objects.

```
const result = my_obj.map(obj => {
  if (obj['id'] === '1') {
    return {...obj, ...merge_obj}
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Also, just a quick advice, try to use `const` and `let` instead of `var`!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate the original just loop over your array and assign directly

```js
var my_obj = [{
    id: "1",
    logo: "img1.png",
    name: "fund",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "2000"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    logo: "img2.png",
    name: "transfer",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "3000"
  },
]

var merge_obj = {
  targetAmount: 50688.97,
  type: "REGULAR"
};

my_obj.forEach(e=> {if(e.id==='1') Object.assign(e, merge_obj)})

console.log(my_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the object accessor in the map function from `e[0]` to `e` only, and check if that works. 
i.e.

```
var filtervalue = myList.filter((e)=>e.id == "1").map((e)=>Object.assign({}, e, merge_obj));
```

Also, you need to check your variable names properly whether its `my_obj` or `myList`.